# SpringBoot application giving RestClientException (Unknown status code [494] null) 2 days after deploying to EC2 instance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, resttemplate, http-status-codes

Our application is a spring batch application running on EC2.

We have a RestTemplate call to an external application and it works fine.
But after 2 days, it started to fail.
we checked with the external application and logs shows the rest service response was successful from their end.
But our application log shows the below exception.
We tried redeploying our application and this behaviour still persists(works for 2 days and fails after that).

We are using spring boot 1.5.9 version.

```
2019-07-04 19:50:38.078 [10.174.81.249:SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2380]
Exception when getting data : org.springframework.web.client.UnknownHttpStatusCodeException: Unknown status code [494] null
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:688)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
```

Comment: for every call I am adding " restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() );"   is this causing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found status code **494 Request header too large** is used by nginx and spring has not covered this status as it is not from the standard.

Please look `enum org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`

Also `org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler`

**Solution:** You have to check your configuration to verify which header is too large.

Comment: It works for 2 days and fails after that. It has only header "Accept".